# Will new kafka node able to work with a existing topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Suppose we have a three node kafka cluster and while creating a topic only two node was active. And after that if we bring the third node back will it able to catch up all the data of this newly created topic. I tried bring down the other two node after the third node came up and when i describe the third node didn't act as leader of the partitions.

```
Topic: test PartitionCount: 6   ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: none    Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0
Topic: test Partition: 1    Leader: none    Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 0
Topic: test Partition: 2    Leader: none    Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0
Topic: test Partition: 3    Leader: none    Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 0
Topic: test Partition: 4    Leader: none    Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0
Topic: test Partition: 5    Leader: none    Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 0
```

Its showing none instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic you created has `ReplicationFactor: 2`. This means only 2 brokers have the data of this topic.

As you had 2 brokers (0 and 1) running, these were picked to be the replicas. You can see all replicas for all partitions are on 0 and 1. No other brokers have data for this topic.

When you start a third broker, it won't be hosting a copy of this topic. So it's not going to be able to become leader.

If you want the third broker to also be a replica, you can extend the replication factor to 3, for example following https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_increase_replication_factor

Note that you won't be able to create a topic with replication factor set to 3 if you only have 2 brokers running.

Comment: Understood that wont partition get extended to the newly available broker. Then how we can say that kafka is horizontally scalable?

Comment: It's horizonally scalable because you can add brokers and add partitions to increase the capacity of a cluster. You can use tools like Cruise Control https://github.com/linkedin/cruise-control to perform the operations you described